# How to plot a range according to selection order?

Tags: excel, vba

I noticed that vba ignores the selection order when I use range command. In my code when I plot A in X axis and B in Y axis it works fine. However I don't know how to tell it to reverse the ordinates. Even when I use `rng1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B,A:A")` it still arranges the series in previous order. My data are in a table and I am concerned to keep the plotting commands as I already used.
Anyone can help me?

```
Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A,B:B")

With ws
    .Shapes.AddChart
    Set objChrt = .ChartObjects(.ChartObjects.Count)
    Set chrt = objChrt.Chart
    With chrt
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
        .SetSourceData Source:=rng1
    End With
End With
```

Comment: I am trying to build up a new range with different order. `rng21 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B")` & `rng22 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")` and finally the modified range as `Set rng2 = Range(rng21.Address & "," & rng22.Address)`. But again returns the same results with the same order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign values to X and Y axis individually.

Assuming you want to plot 2 series, this should work:

```
Sub create_chart()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rngX1 As Range
Dim rngY1 As Range
Dim rngX2 As Range
Dim rngY2 As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheets1")
Set rngX1 = Worksheets("Sheets1").Range("A:A")
Set rngY1 = Worksheets("Sheets1").Range("B:B")
Set rngX2 = Worksheets("Sheets1").Range("C:C")
Set rngY2 = Worksheets("Sheets1").Range("D:D")

With ws
    .Shapes.AddChart
    Set objChrt = .ChartObjects(.ChartObjects.Count)
    Set chrt = objChrt.Chart
    With chrt
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
        'series 1
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = rngX1
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = rngY1
        'series 2
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = rngX2
        .SeriesCollection(2).Values = rngY2
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

It's a bit slow due to the ranges, you should limit it to fit your data.

Comment: We need to create the SeriesCollection first. I'm gonna edit my answer.

Comment: so, how can I add a second data series to this plot? I added these: `Set rng2Y = Worksheets("Sheets1").Range("A:A")`
`Set rng2X = Worksheets("Sheets1").Range("C:C")` and `.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = rng2Y`
        `.SeriesCollection(2).Values = rng2X` but on this line `.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = rng2Y` the code returns Run-time error 1004.

Comment: and of course defined  `Dim rng2X As Range` `Dim rng2Y As Range`,

Comment: You have to call .SeriesCollection.NewSeries again. I just updated my answer.